# I can't read in Burmese in Firefox!

Tags: firefox, fonts

I can't read in Burmese in Firefox. What can I do? Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried forcing a font that support Burmese in Firefox.
Edit > Preferences > Contents: Fonts

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you review [A Guide to Using Myanmar Unicode](http://my.duniakitab.com/ThanLwinSoft/ThanLwinSoft/MyanmarUnicode/Fonts/) and then add fonts which support it, which are linked from that web page.